Azure Function Eventhub output binding (typescript) - how to set Key/Headers with programming model v4
Using an output binding for Eventhub it was possible to add furhter message properties like Key/Headers in the v3 programming model, as shown in the examples:
context.bindings.outputKafkaMessage = ["{ \"Offset\":364,\"Partition\":0,\"Topic\":\"kafkaeventhubtest1\",\"Timestamp\":\"2022-04-09T03:20:06.591Z\", \"Value\": \"one\", \"Headers\": [{ \"Key\": \"test\", \"Value\": \"javascript\" }] }",
    "{ \"Offset\":364,\"Partition\":0,\"Topic\":\"kafkaeventhubtest1\",\"Timestamp\":\"2022-04-09T03:20:06.591Z\", \"Value\": \"two\", \"Headers\": [{ \"Key\": \"test\", \"Value\": \"javascript\" }] }"]

This also worked for the Eventhub bindings. But it fails in the v4 programming model, as the whole object is just produced as a message to Eventhub.
Migrated my existing Azure function to v4, set the specific output.eventHub property and testes producing messages to this binding.
Instead of receiving the Value property as a message with the Key and Headers properties set as Key and Headers respectively the whole object was published as a message to Eventhub, with no set Key or Headers.
